# Running UIAutomation instruments from command line results in NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: command-line, instruments, xcode4.5, ios-ui-automation, ios6

Here is what is happening:

I create a brand new "Single View" application in Xcode 4.5.1, build it on the command line using this:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/tmp/AutomationBugRepro
```

[Which results in this output](https://gist.github.com/3834304) and a successful build.  Now when I run a UIAutomation script with `instruments`, I get the following error:

```
2012-10-04 11:27:33.930 instruments[4707:f07] Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  NSInvalidArgumentException
2012-10-04 15:27:33 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
```

And the command I used to run this:

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D ./trace /tmp/AutomationBugRepro/AutomationBugRepro2.app -e UIARESULTSPATH ./automation_results -e UIASCRIPT automation.js
```

`automation.js` contains just this one line:

```
UIALogger.logMessage("Testing UIAutomation from the command line");
```

I'm also getting an unspecified error when trying to do any automation stuff in the instruments GUI, which I detailed in this apple dev forum post:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/169338

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, I'm trying to run the app in the simulator, not on a device.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Xcode installed?

Comment: It was running good with sample javascript file but when I added new custom script file it started giving error and even setting back the sample script file didn't work.